# Android SFTP resumable download file

Tags: java, android, download, sftp, jsch

In my project I want to use SFTP download process.Specially for resume download..
I used this lib for my android download project.

I used **JSCH** library for this.

I know only this library if there is any other method or API please let me know

for resume download process I follow the standard example which on its website..

[SFTP Resume Download](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java)

But its not working ..

*Actully value of **"i"** display **-1**  so , It not coming inside the loop*

please help me to resolve the issue...

Anybody facing same issue for this...

Comment: @comonsware here is my doubts if possible please reply me..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our commercial library, [edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html), works on Android and supports resume in SFTP.