# How to downlaod a certain image from firebase storage based on a value in firebase firestore in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to download certain images from firebase storage (by adding the downlaodURLs to a list) based on some values taken from firebase firestore. More precisely I want to download an image from firebase storage, if its downloadURL's string value contains the name taken from a document in firestore.
The code is given below.

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference ref = firestore.collection("games");
    ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                String formattedName = ((String) document.getData().get("name")).replaceAll(" ", "-").replaceAll(":", "").replaceAll("'","");
                imageNames.add(formattedName);
            }

            download(listRef, imageNames);
        }
    });
```

When I call the function download(), I keep taking a message on the console saying :

"W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
No App Check token for request."

The code for download() is given below.

```
public void download(StorageReference listRef, ArrayList<String> formattedNames){
    listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for(StorageReference file:listResult.getItems()){
                file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        if(formattedNames.contains(uri.toString())){
                            imagelist.add(uri.toString());
                            Log.e("Itemvalue","" + uri.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As far as I understood I can't do what I want because onComplete() and onSuccess() work asynchronously, can someone help me?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848499/how-to-download-multiple-images-from-urls-in-a-single-process

Comment: So what's wrong with shared code?