# how to download image from url android

Tags: android, kotlin, download, android-download-manager, imagedownload

please dont mark it as duplicate...i referring to this answer--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986577/12553303

nothing is happening on click of button...not getting download

```
 download.setOnClickListener {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            applicationContext,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {

                        // this will request for permission when user has not granted permission for the app
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@Product_details,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                            1)
                    } else {
                        //Download Script
                        val downloadManager: DownloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                        val uri = Uri.parse(product_images)
                        val request: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                           uri.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                            uri.lastPathSegment)
                        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
                    }
                }
```

where `product_image` ==>`val product_images:String =intent1.getStringExtra("image")`

need help thanks

Comment: have you add permission in manifest file?

Comment: yes i added @AmrishKakadiya ...

Comment: DO away with that permission code. Its enough that you tell us that you have permissions. Just start the downloadmanager . For which you do not need any permission.

Comment: no i dont see that toast @blackapps

Comment: If you dont see that Toast then better remove all permissin code as i said before.

Comment: i put a log on product_image i get a link of image in log --> E/product_images: http://xx.xxx/medium/3d4007c74793ff2564de15d71.jpeg @blackapps

Comment: @blackapps i removed permission ...removed that if part...it worked ..thanks...make this as an answer  with explanantion so that i can upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do away with that permission code.

Just start the downloadmanager .

For which you do not need any permission.

Comment: hi can u help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76480901/facing-issue-while-making-dynamic-views-using-relative-layout

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso or Glide library to download images from URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this Picasso library

Tthis Link : [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
    Picasso.with(MainActivity::this)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(imageView, object: com.squareup.picasso.Callback {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        //set animations here

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: java.lang.Exception?) {
                        //do smth when there is picture loading error
                    }
                })
```